# How to make sure a WAR file is uploaded to OpenShift and how to deploy it?

Tags: java, openshift, war

I could transfer my war file using scp on OpenShift. However it just showed that the update is 100% and nothing else. I pressed enter and used ctrl+c to go back to terminal to no luck.
Therefore, I closed the terminal and opened a new one.

I need to know how can I make sure the file is successfully transfered and how to deploy the uploaded WAR file?